# Running Symfony2 command (propel:build) within PHP script

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I want to run a console command within a PHP script. Usually it's done via the CLI, so I tried to edit it and the result is as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Propel\PropelBundle\Command\BuildCommand;

set_time_limit(0);

require_once '/home/core/site/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once '/home/core/site/app/AppKernel.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$application = new Application($kernel);//->find('propel:build');
$application->setAutoExit(false);
$application->add(new BuildCommand());

$input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'propel:build', '--insert-sql' => true));
$output = new BufferedOutput();
$application->run($input, $output);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output->fetch());
```

But my output is `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException] You have requested a non-existent service "propel.configuration"`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the problem is that you access the services container to early. Try accessing it after `$application->run($input, $output);`. The container should be accessible via `$kernel->getContainer()`.